# How to get jobs in a particular "DONE" state

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to determine various job states. Bigquery provides three states that I am aware of: [DONE, PENDING, and RUNNING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs). However, I'm trying to get states based on the following:

- Done
- Pending
- Successful
- Error
- Cancelled
- Running

How would I do this in a way that isn't too 'expensive', as I'm iterating over about 100 results in a sort of "long-poll" fashion, about once every ten seconds. Currently I'm doing something like:

```
jobs = [job for job in self.bq_client.list_jobs(project=PROJECT_ID]
if state is not None:
    jobs = [job for job in jobs if job.state == state]
```

The above works if the state is one of DONE, RUNNING, or PENDING. But how would I cover the other states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State tracks job progress and if you need success/fail information you want to look into the `errorResult` of the [response](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list). For successful jobs this will be `None`, for cancelled ones you'll get `{u'reason': u'stopped', u'message': u'Job execution was cancelled: User requested cancellation'}`. The code I used to test this:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

project = "[PROJECT-ID]"
states = ["RUNNING", "PENDING", "SUCCESSFUL", "CANCELLED", "FAILED"]


def returnState(job):
  if job.state == "DONE":
    if job.error_result is None:
      return "SUCCESSFUL"
    elif job.error_result['reason'] == u'stopped':
      return "CANCELLED"
    else:
      return "FAILED"
  else:
    return job.state


jobs = [job for job in client.list_jobs(project=project, max_results=10)]

for state in states:
  matching_jobs = [job for job in jobs if returnState(job) == state]

  for job in matching_jobs:
    print "Job ID: {0}, State: {1}, Error Result: {2}".format(job.job_id, state, job.error_result)
```

This will print out something like:

```py
$ python bq-status.py
Job ID: bquijob_..., State: SUCCESSFUL, Error Result: None
Job ID: bquijob_..., State: SUCCESSFUL, Error Result: None
Job ID: job_..., State: SUCCESSFUL, Error Result: None
Job ID: job_..., State: SUCCESSFUL, Error Result: None
Job ID: job_..., State: SUCCESSFUL, Error Result: None
Job ID: job_..., State: SUCCESSFUL, Error Result: None
Job ID: scheduled_query_..., State: SUCCESSFUL, Error Result: None
Job ID: bquijob_..., State: SUCCESSFUL, Error Result: None
Job ID: bquijob_..., State: CANCELLED, Error Result: {u'reason': u'stopped', u'message': u'Job execution was cancelled: User requested cancellation'}
Job ID: bquijob_..., State: FAILED, Error Result: {u'reason': u'invalidQuery', u'message': u'Syntax error: Illegal input character "\\\\" at [2:18]', u'location': u'query'}
```

Keep in mind that load jobs might be successful but allow for some `maxBadRecords` so that `errorResult` will be not empty, etc.

Comment: awesome, thanks for this. I'm actually looking for someone to advise on some areas (BQ, Cloud Dataflow) for a large application. Would it be ok if I sent you an email with details? My email is deemarklit@gmail.com if it's ok to reach out -- thanks.